# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at .....

Tags: angularjs

When using $http.get I have a problem:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ..... This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS

```
$http.get('...').success(function(data){
        console.log(status);
    }).error(function(data){
        //console.log(data)
    });
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross-origin requests are requests made from one domain to a different one (in client side). They are by default prohibited in the Web for security reasons. So, if you have a webpage in http://www.yours.com making an AJAX request to http://www.other.com/get/resource, then this AJAX request will be rejected. This issue can be resolved in 3 ways :

- "Relocate" the API (/get/resource) to the `www.yours.com` domain (i.e. http://www.yours.com/get/resource), so that the AJAX request is not crossing domains anymore.
- Transform the architecture of your application, so that this request from http://www.yours.com is made in the backend (aka not in the form of AJAX) and then passed on your webpage.
- Enable the server in http://www.other.com to allow CORS requests from http://www.yours.com. This can be done by adding the header `Origin: http://www.yours.com` in the responses of the server. Thus, it requires that you have access to the second server's configuration.

Additional Resources for CORS :

1. [HTML5 turorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)
2. [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: @Dimos i followed your suggestion but i'm unnable to slove the CROS problem. I'm using this github project `https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample`. Added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the common/headers. Still not able to slove the problem.

Comment: If I am not making a terrible mistake, I think the headers in this file correspond to the headers that will be sent by the browser during an HTTP AJAX request. However, you need to add the `Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in you server configuration, so that it allows AJAX requests from different domains.

Comment: Pretty succinct answer. +1. What do you mean by `Fetch the API` by the way?

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano thanks for calling this out. It was so ambiguous that I even struggled a bit to understand what I was thinking 3 years ago! I meant relocating this API to the domain www.yours.com, so that the AJAX request does not cross domains. I'll update my answer to make it a bit more clear.